# Bing API Report Unzip

Tags: zip, bing-api

I'm loading a CSV file from Bing Reporting API.  The documentation says "The report file is compressed; therefore, you must unzip it to read the report.", so I save the raw file as shown in the example, but I can't get SharpZipLib, 7Zip, or WinRar to read the compressed data.

How can I decompress Bing API reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I was able to get SharpZipLib to read the compressed data, but only after copying it to a seek-able memory stream first.  This isn't the best solution for arbitrarily large files, but I'm reasonably confident our specific data won't get too large.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading some bing reports can be a bit of a song an dance - but the flow is somewhat like this -

- request the report ( returns a report id )
- start polling to see when the report is ready
- when the report is ready you will get a url where you can download the zip file
- unzip the file, and do what you need - but to answer your question.....
- below is a very simplified example of simply extracting the zip and saiving somewhere - hope this helps, and good luck to ya

  ```
  $zip_filepath = "location of the zip file";
  $archive = new ZipArchive();
  // file extension of extracted file

  if ($archive->open($zip_filepath) !== true) {
      throw new \Exception ("Decompress operation from ZIP file failed. Contact Ratio Rick");
  }

  $a = $archive->statIndex(0); 
  $file_name = $a['name'];

  $save_path = "enter save file path";

  $archive->extractTo($path . $file_name);
  $archive->close();
  ```